# C#.NET form submit unable to get new/modified values for form elements

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am creating a ASP.NET page in C# to add/modify details and then save those details in MySQL database. For this I have created a master page "Main.Master" a web content form "modify.aspx" and its code behind.
Code for "Main.Master" is as given below. Master contains form tag declaration.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.Main" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainmasterform" method="post" runat="server">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="maincontent">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for "modify.aspx" is as given below. Only form elements are present in this page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="modify.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.modify" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="ownfname">First Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox id="ownfname" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="ownlname">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox id="ownlname" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="submitowner" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="modifyDetails" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

On click of "submitowner" button submits "modify.aspx" to a controller method "modifyDetails" present in "modify.aspx.cs" code behind file. "modifyDetails" code is as follows.

```
protected void modifyDetails(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string cmdstr = "UPDATE owners SET first_name=?, last_name=? WHERE userid=?";
        OdbcConnection odbccon = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL55"].ConnectionString);
        OdbcCommand odbccmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdstr, odbccon);
        string fname = ownfname.Text;
        string lname = ownlname.Text;
        odbccmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = fname;
        odbccmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = lname;
        odbccmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", OdbcType.Int).Value = userid;
        odbccon.Open();
        odbccmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

Now I am facing trouble in getting new values of form elements. As for example when the web page is rendered text within "ownfname" is "Robert" and then you modify it to "David" then click on submit button. After submitting accessing the "ownfname.Text" property still gives "Robert" and not "David". I tried searching for a solution but no luck.

I am not able to understand what is the exact problem here.
Is the code wrong? Can anyone help me figure out the issue/problem ?
I apologize for such a long question.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't work please provide more information on how the form fields are populated and provide some more of your code beind page (.aspx.cs page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading the initial values into your form fields on page load you need to use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
        //Populate form fields
     }
}
```

This will ensure that the fields are not overwritten on post back.

If you're not overly familiar with the ASP.net page life cycle [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is well worth the read. It explains the order of events when an asp.net page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon P. Your solution worked for me. Can u guide me to a documentation/tutorial to understand this concept ?

Comment: Have a look at the article I just added it help explains the cycle pretty well. Another trick I did in my early days was add debug break points to each of the events I was using (page load, on button click etc) then debug the page so I would get a better understanding of what would run when. After you've read the article, accepting my answer would be appreciated (click the tick). An upvote would be nice too (click the up arrow)